# How can I invoke an Albacore rake task in a multithreaded way?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rake, albacore

I have a set of tasks in a Rakefile.  I use `MultiTask::invoke` in order to invoke them in parallel, and it seems to work fine.  These tasks eventually all share an Albacore task (an `exec`).  This `Exec` task seems to have some kind of a bottleneck, whereby it runs in serial instead of in parallel.  Is there some way to force Albacore to use `MultiTask` in order to run my `Exec`s in parallel?

Comment: Can you provide your Rakefile or this invoke call so we can have some more context?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `Task::invoke`, call `Task::Execute`.